# jQuery Draggable class finding

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have three classes in html tag. i gave draggable for one class. How can i know the class value.

```
<div class="drag dgtf hgyh">
  //content 
</div>

<div class="drop">
  //content 
</div>
```

Jquery as follows

```
$('.drag').draggable({
  drag:function(){}
})

$('.drop').draggable({
  drop:function(event, ui){
    // here i need to get particular class which has drag
    // that is how can i get 'drag' class name
  }
})
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Please clarify and make a proper question.

Comment: I need the class name of the draggable after dropped @SorangwalaAbbasali

Comment: Do you want to get class name of dropped element?

Comment: yes after dropping i need exact class name of dropped element  @GovindSamrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get class of dropped element.

```
$('.drop').draggable({
  drop:function(event, ui){
      var draggable_class = ui.draggable[0].attr("class");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
drop:function(event, ui){
 ui.draggable.attr("id") // For ID
 ui.draggable.attr("class") // For Class
}
```

Update :

```
 ui.draggable.attr("class").split(' ')[0] // May be 1 or 2
```

Comment: for class gets 3 class names and i need only 'drag' class

Comment: split class name with space and see on console which index is drag class appear and take a class in jquery just like ` ui.draggable.attr("class").split(' ')[0]`

Comment: I am actually expecting dynamic answer @Shree